# Is Ruby Koans compatible with ruby 2.6.1?

Tags: ruby

Just starting with Ruby Koans as a way to practice aside from traditional homework.

Following the outlined instructions on the Koans site it says to run

```
ruby path_to_enlightenment.rb
```

which should return

```
[ ruby_koans ] $ ruby 
path_to_enlightenment.rb
(in /Users/person/dev/ruby_koans)
cd koans

Thinking AboutAsserts
test_assert_truth has damaged your karma.

You have not yet reached enlightenment ...
<false> is not true.

Please meditate on the following code:
./about_asserts.rb:10:in `test_assert_truth'
path_to_enlightenment.rb:27

mountains are merely mountains
```

but instead is returning

```
ruby path_to_enlightenment.rb

Thinking AboutAsserts
test_assert_truth has damaged your karma.

You have not yet reached enlightenment ...
<false> is not true.

Please meditate on the following code:
Traceback (most recent call last):
    2: from 
/mnt/c/Users/skywalker/ruby_koans/koans/edgecase.rb:265:in `block in <top (required)>'
1: from /mnt/c/Users/skywalker/ruby_koans/koans/edgecase.rb:112:in `report'
/mnt/c/Users/skywalker/ruby_koans/koans/edgecase.rb:102:in `assert_failed?': uninitialized constant 
EdgeCase::Sensei::AssertionError (NameError)
```

Would anyone know why im getting this unitialized constant error ?

```
 uninitialized constant 
EdgeCase::Sensei::AssertionError (NameError)
```

I highly doubt the very first test would ask be to fix an unitialized constant error and no where in the read does it say to do so. Would you know why im getting this error and how i could fix it ?

The only thing i can think of is maybe Koans is not compatible with Ruby 2.6 ?

Comment: I think they must have not updated their README or something, it worked for me to just run `rake` but there isn't even a `path_to_enlightenment.rb` file in the place the README says

Comment: yeah so i tried to run rake but it responds "cannot run file" after i just i just installed it